# Low-DC-resistance inductors?

Tags: filter, inductor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwPBdW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: noise filter diagram]

I have a 5V DC source that passes AC noise (alternator whine, spark plug discharge through the smoke-lighter-to-micro-USB port) in my A2DP bluetooth receiver, which passes it along to the headphone jack Aux input on car stereo. This A2DP bluetooth receiver it powers needs under 50mA, likely 20.

I want to make a low pass filter that will only pass everything under 200hz or so.
Modelling the 50mA load roughly as a resistor gives me a real component of 1k ohms, which requires a not-significant imaginary component (aka large inductor) to begin the attenuation at the pole where (R+jwL)=0.

What do I do about this? BTW, two doesn't really help.

[image: filter simulation]

Comment: 1. What does your 12V -> 5V converter look like? 2. Does your load draw a steady current or does it vary? If it varies, how much?

Comment: Look for a ferrite bead

Comment: @Will, ferrite beads are for HF filtering, 1Mhz. I can't hear that high!

Answer (score 2):

An inductor with low DCR and high inductance is basically going to equate to thick wire around some kind of core and generally be somewhat large. Such a part is usually called a "choke", not an inductor. Try searching Mouser for "choke" instead maybe. For whatever reason you don't see parts like that as a stock part. I guess manufacturers would just build something like that according to a particular application. Inductance of 100mH is somewhat high. Usually power chokes are uH and BIG thick wire around a ferrite core. If this is a one-off project search for "choke" on ebay maybe. Or break open an old computer power supply and desolder the best looking choke using a solder braid. Coupled with the largest capacitor you can find, that might filter enough.

Or use one of those little DC converters that are $10 for 10 on ebay. Those things actually work pretty well. At 100 mA it might get a little hot but it shouldn't be any hotter than your smoke-lighter-to-microUSB thingy since they're both just switching regulators.

Comment: why would a DC converter work when my lighter-mUSB doesn't?

Comment: That's a good question. What doesn't work about it? I'm no DC converter guru but it seems to me there could be a huge difference in the quality of implementation. A good step down converter would run at a high freq. like 50 kHz and have a decent output filter. Your lighter-mUSB might just be a piece of crap. So you might want to just diagnose what doesn't work about it. Is there too much noise? Maybe your just sucking too much power from it and it's failing to regulate the noise out in which case you might just go out and buy a bigger one.

Comment: yes, too much noise. It's part of the assy provided with the bluetooth a2dp-to-aux-port. It also has a port for phone charging (1A), so maybe it's just not sampling at 50khz. But that's helpful-- Stage 2 of this project is doing the same for that 1A line-- if you've ever charged your phone and listened to music through stereo aux port at same time, you hear the alternator  and spark plug whine. Probably not a huge deal, but it would be nice to have a perfectly clean signal so I don't have to worry about the HF components hurting the cell battery charge cycle any. And this stuff is good review.

Answer (score 2):

100mH is actually a pretty high inductance for a power inductor. In fact, 100uH is rather high (newer switching power supplies often use 10uH or less).

You may be able to use a common-mode choke. One example would be a 90mH Schaffner [EV35-1.0-02-90M](http://schaffner.com/en/products/datasheet-low-res/product/eveh-series-common-mode-chokes.pdf), but you can do your own parametric search. It has 0.628 ohm (per side or total, not sure what the spec refers to without digging) resistance so it would drop about 1/8 or 1/16 volt at 100mA.

They will saturate at a relatively low current if the currents through the two sides are not balanced (and if they are, the inductance cancels out).

[image]

If the problem is power supply noise on the power ground relative to the signal (also ground-referenced) then filtering the power supply will **not** help. You may wish to isolate either the power supply (DC-DC converter) or the audio signal (transformer, at some cost in signal fidelity). Auto stereo shops (even WalMart) sell transformers for exactly this purpose, but they may call them something else.

I would suggest a galvanically isolated DC-DC converter if this is the problem because it will probably be less expensive and it won't add audio distortion.

Comment: I've tried the transformer route, sounds attrocious.

is there no low-resistance series-inductor because the windings have to be tight (small wire->resistance) to give high reactive resistance?

yes, it's for the power line/ground line that are going to the bluetooth A2DP receiver. In my ideal mind I just buy two put them in line and those get ride of HF components. What about installing bypass caps?

Comment: I would try the isolated DC-DC converter and isolate the supply. You could also try a differential stage to isolate the signal from ground without a transformer.

Comment: can you define "balanced"-- is that wrt flux (flux cancels), or current direction (flux adds)?

Comment: Flux (and thus inductance) cancels for differential signals, but they act as relatively high value series paralleled inductors for common mode noise (hence the name).

Comment: I think I'm actually modelling this wrong and my calculations are off. Can my load estimate just be a resistor to ground that permits the measured current?

Comment: @Rancur3p1c I think it's going to be more complex. If you draw the actual schematic with ground and signal paths you probably have the makings of a good modelling question, and someone will help.

Comment: added some schematics. I just realized I can reduce the load's component by putting a capacitor in parallel, will update mathcad model soon

Answer (score 1):

Sound like the perfect job for a transistor capacitance multiplier.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance_multiplier.

Put it between the 12V and 5V regulator.
(Maybe a TIP31?)  R ~ 1 kohm, maybe 0.5K, and a nice big Al cap.)

Comment: that looks almost exactly like what I want. I wasn't planning on breaking out my analog electronics course work but this might be my inspiration

Comment: but idk if can handle 0.65v lower
wait. no I don't think I can put that between the 5 and 12v lines. This is on a car we're talking about. transistor can't even out the entire 12, oh, hm

Comment: The voltage drop Vce will not be 0.65V... typically it's more like 1 Volt.. but it depends on how much base current you feed it (It drops as you make the base resistor smaller.... but then you get less R/C filtering, a trade off.) and on the load current.  This won't regulate your entire 12V to 5 Volts, but it will clean up the 12V signal.

Comment: how much regulation does it need to provide if this is in a car? There's likely a lot of stray capacitance. Perhaps if I place it right next to the 12v->5v step down that will be sufficient?